# Times of nested algorithms in proofs of security

Tags: provable-security, adversarial-model

Proofs of security may be constructed such that an adversary $A$ is used to construct an adversary $A'$.
The reduction/algorithm which uses $A$ has to perform a number of computations in order to simulate the environnement of $A$ (t.i.t.s to intercept/answer to queries from $A$).

I've noticed that we evaluate the time $t'$ taken by $A'$ such that $t'=t+n \cdot t_c$ where $t$ is the time taken by $A$, $n$ is the number of computations made by the reduction and $t_c$ the time to perform one computation.

I don't understand why we generally conclude that $t \ge t' - n \cdot t_c$. I don't understand why we remove the quantity $n \cdot t_c$. It seems to me that $A$ and $A'$ terminate at virtually the same time ($A'$ uses the output from $A$ almost immediately).

An example: Assume that a computation needs $1$ unit of time. An algorithm $A'$ uses $A$ as follows:

- $A$ makes a query (the elapsed time for $A$ and $A'$ is $1$)
- $A'$ makes a computation and responds to $A$ (the overall elapsed time for $A$ and $A'$ is 2)
- $A$ makes a query (the overall elapsed time for $A$ and $A'$ is $3$)
- $A'$ makes a computation and responds to $A$ (the overall elapsed time for $A$ and $A'$ is 4)
- etc ...
- when $A$ terminates and gives the result to $A'$, we assume there is not need for more computations. It seems that $A$ and $A'$ terminate at the same time.

We see in this example that it's strange for $A$ to remove the time of computations (unless these computations are considered as "free").

Comment: It is not the case that $A'$ terminates when $A$ terminates. $A'$ may require some more computations to transform the output of $A$ into a solution to the respective problem $A'$ is required to solve.

Comment: @DrLecter Yes I've supposed that $A'$ doesn't need more computations at the end so as to show what is the problem.

Comment: Even if $A'$ makes more computation after having obtained the output from $A$ this does not explain why there is a "pause" (in the elapsed time for $A$) when $A$ is waiting for the response to a query !

Comment: Thanks DrLecter. An oracle call requires (or doesn't require ?) unit time ? What is referred to the simulation of an oracle call ? I don't understand what this means.

Comment: When I say that I don't understand why "there is a "pause" (in the elapsed time for A) when A is waiting for the response to a query", I'm speaking about a simulated oracle since this is $A'$ which responds to $A$.

Comment: Thank DrLecter. If you set to $0$ the communication times in my example there is always a problem... Imagines that $A$ makes a query ($0$ unit of  times), $A'$ receives the query and performs a computation ($1$ unit of time) and responds to $A$ ($0$ unit of time). For $A$ as well as for $A'$, the amount of time elapsed is $1$. Not ?

Comment: You may take a look into Dan Boneh's paper, e.g., [this one](http://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480516.pdf) to see how one accounts for oracle queries in the run-times within reductions.

Comment: Thanks DRLecter, "\textbf{yes}, but A has to do something and not only make oracle calls to be successful". In fact the subject of my question was why we can remove the time to performs the set of queries (namely $n \cdot t_c$). Thanks for the paper.

Comment: Its already too late today to formulate meaningul answers :) I'll try it with an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to have in mind that $A$ is a hypothetical algorithm, since our goal in the reduction is to contradict the existence of such an efficient $A$.

Now to your concrete security framework: Here, you are not satisfied by the fact that a hypothetical poly-time $A$ implies a poly-time reduction $A'$, but your aim is that the reduction does not take significantly more time than $A$ and you want to quantify that difference. So you want to relate the running time $t$ of such an hypothetical $A$ to the runtime $t'$ of the reduction $A'$ where $A'$ simulates the environment of the real attack game for $A$ such that $A$ cannot distinguish the real game from the simulated game in the reduction.

What you already observed in your question is the runtime of $A'$ is $t'=t+n \cdot t_c$, where $t$ is the time taken by $A$, $n$ is the number of computations made by the reduction and $t_c$ the time to perform one computation (such as an exponentiation of a group element). The term $n\cdot t_c$ typically includes all the overhead that $A'$ has to make, transformations required to the problem instance that $A'$ receives in order to "give" it to $A$ as part of some parameters or as answers to oracle queries and transforming the output of $A$ to a solution to the instance of the input problem if necessary. Furthermore, the operations that are required the answer the oracle calls that $A$ makes to the oracles that are simulated by $A'$. Often you will also encounter in such concrete reductions that the number of oracle queries and the associated costs are made more explicit. Anyways, observe that the runtime of $A$ does not include the time the oracles require to answer since this is counted in the $n\cdot t_c$ term (this is work done by $A'$, since it simulates the oracles for $A$).

Actually, I think there is a bug in your question, since I think you mean that  $t'\leq t+n \cdot t_c$ which is simply since your constructed reduction $A'$ gives an upper bound on the runtime (there may be more efficient reductions $A''$, which you did not figure out, but you have one and it can only get better. Hence the $\leq$).

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to explain me. Why you say that the "subalgorithms" of A simulate the challenger and the oracles ? This is not $A'$ (t.i.t.s. the reduction) which simulates the environment of $A$ ?

Comment: @Dingo13 The reduction $A'$ is an algorithm were you put a problem in and get the solution out. But internally $A'$ simulates the challenger and oracles for $A$. Thus I wrote "subalgorithms" of $A'$ for the parts of $A'$ that do these tasks. Anyways thats only one "big" algorithm $A'$ when viewed from the outside. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I've read "subalgorithms" of $A$ in your answer. In fact I've already understood your comments. There is only small details that are a problem for me. You say that oracle queries costs $1$ unit of time. Why they don't appear in the times of proofs by reduction ? It seems to me that if we have $q$ oracle calls, we should take into account the amount of time $q$, not ?

Comment: @Dingo13 thats already counted in the operations $A'$ makes, since the oracles are simulated by $A'$.

Comment: I make the distinction between simulated oracle and "real" oracle. I thought in your explanation that "real" oracle queries costs $1$ whereas "simulated" oracle costs the time to make the needed computations.

Comment: @Dingo13 remember that $A$ is a hypothetical algorithm and the runtime of $A$ in the reduction is without the runtimes of the oracles as they are counted as operations that $A'$ performs. Hope this clears your confusion now :)

Comment: Thanks DrLecter, so, when you say that oracle queries costs $1$ you speak of simulated oracle, and real oracle queries (for instance when $A'$ uses itself an oracle) costs "nothing". That's right ?

Comment: @Dingo13 I removed the part in the beginning since I think this confuses you and tried to clarify the oracle stuff in the reduction.

Comment: DrLecter, my previous comment is right ?

Comment: @Dingo13 You have to remember that $A$ is a hypothetical algorithm that wins the security game. If you use $A$ in your reduction, then you simulate ALL oracles for $A$ and count the time required for the oracle calls in the time that $A'$ requires. There are no other oracles that $A$ can access.

Comment: @Dingo13 To add up: It doesn't matter how $A$ really works and how the oracles do their task in the real game, since this is only a "thought experiment". Your aim is just to show that if such an efficient $A$ would exist, then you could use it as a black box and simulate the oracles in such a way that your hypothetical $A$ would not realize that $A'$ is simulating the environment for $A$. And in your reduction $A'$ you count the costs for your oracle simulations in addition to the "pure" runtime of $A$. I know that's a bit weird, but that's how it goes :)

Answer (score 4):

The equation $t'=t+n\cdot t_c$ is an estimation to put an upper limit on $t'$. It might be possible that an attacker $A'$ can use a different, more efficient algorithm. But since the attack will work with using $A$, there exists an attacker $A'$ with at most $t'$. This means it's actually not an equation, but an inequality $t' \leq t + n \cdot t_c$. And then the next step is just a standard transformation to get $t'  - n \cdot t_c \leq t$.

*Edit:*
Actually, this assumes that $A'$ only has to run $A$ once. There are also reductions which run $A$ multiple times. If you are only looking for asymptotical complexity, it doesn't change much, tho. Running a polynomial time algorithm polynomial many times is still polynomial overall.

*Edit2*:
Concerning your example, there are a couple of misunderstandings of of the these times. First, in a reduction we use $A$ mostly as a blackbox. We can observe the queries (e.g. if we assume an oracle for that, which can be accessed by both $A$ and $A'$). But we make no assumptions about these times. Saying that $A'$ takes 1 unit of time for a calculation and $A$ needing 1 unit of time for a query (and possibly some internal computations)  is an assumption about their correlation we should not make.

And then there is the question what we actually use from the attacker $A$. Usually we do not only use their queries, but their results. And that happens at the time $A$ is finished, which is $t$. Then $A'$ can do its final transformation of results or do some more complex computations, which is not necessarily instant (e.g. solving a large linear system or doing $k$ exponentiations, etc.). If you assume this to be instant, then $t=t'$ for exactly this attack. But that doesn't mean that this is the fastest attack (if you assume $A'$ to be the "best" attacker, $t'$ might be lower), or if those computations are not instant, then $t'$ might be greater.

Comment: Thanks tylo, I've already understood these things but this does not respond to my misunderstanding. My problem is the following: I don't understand why we can deduct something like that about $t$ since $t$ and $t'$ seem tightly related. When $A'$ performs a computation to respond to a query from $A$, time goes by the same for both. It seems to me that $A$ and $A′$ terminate at virtually the same time ($A′$ uses the output from A almost immediately).

Comment: Maybe it's preferable to give an example ? I'm going to give a concrete example in my post ! :-)

Comment: If we write $t' - n \cdot t_c \leq t$, this means that the computations are free (they take $0$ unit of time). Maybe you will say me that this is normal since we are looking for an upper bound... But this strange anyway (computations are not free)

Comment: That is a wrong conclusion. The computations are bound by $n\cdot t_c \geq t' - t$. But if $A'$ has to do any computations *after* it $A$ terminated and gave the results, they do not end at the same time. Even in your simple example,  the attack $A$ alone does 2 steps of time ($A$ is a standalone algorithm), while $A$ requires to wait for $A$ for 2 units and do 2 computations of its own, so overall $4$ (if you assume the time slots to be equal, and no parallel execution).

Comment: Thanks tylo, I've not understood your last comment because of mistakes when writing... And this is not clear because when $A$ waits for the responses from $A'$, time is always elapsing. Even is $A$ is a standalone algorithm, each waiting takes time...

Comment: $A$ is used to construct $A'$. That means, $A$ exists on its own already. The time $t$ does not state the time required in *this* context, but for the algorithm $A$ alone. $A'$ is based on $A$, so it has to consider the time spent for $A$ as well.

Comment: Thanks @tylo. I perfectly understand that the time of $A'$ is at least the time of $A$, but why can we deduct the time of $A$ ? Since at each query/response, when $A$ is waiting (and is making computations during this waiting) for the response from $A'$, time is elapsing for both...

Comment: It seems I don't understand what you mean. $A$ NEVER waits for $A'$. $A$ does not even know $A'$ exists. $A$ is a full fledged algorithm: You start it with some input, it runs for a certain time (which is $t$) and then it stops. There is no interaction with $A'$.

Comment: If there are oracles calls and responses then there is interaction... I've understood the following:  we assume that $A$ does not make any difference between the simulated oracles and conventional ones (not simulated). Consequently, we have to consider that the interactions are instant.